# Generate reports from logs

Tags: logging, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Company I’m working in is using Jenkins for application testing. We have Failure Build Analyzer 
plug-in configured and running. The plug-in finds error patterns in logs and based on this displays in the Build page what categories of errors have been found. It can mark the line in logs which matched the pattern. Patterns and categories are provided by user (me).

The thing that my boss wants implemented is to have in a Build page a table showing names of tests along with category.

For example:

Test101 | Download error

Test102 | Download error

Test103 | Permissions error

I would like to hear tips how can I achieve like this. I’m very new to Jenkins so very novice tips are welcome. If it can’t be done, I would like to hear ideas how something of sort can be done. Boss is flexible so the requirements aren’t strict.

Edit 1: 
In the end I decided to create executable jar. Jar is run after every build  (as post-step) and generates HTML report based on logs. HTML report is then displayed using HTML Publisher Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We have done some similar thing as you said. What we do is collect the failure info and show it in a web page so that user can have a clear picture about different type of errors.

Our solution is like this:

We use python to parse all of our Jenkins jobs build result json file, such as http://myjenkins/job/hello/123/json/api.

Build failure related info is listed inside the json file.

This python script will be called by one of jenkins job every 10 minutes.

We will push the error related info to a database

After this, you have the error data in database, you can create a simple web page to show the errors.

Br,

Tim